# Android - Handling MTOM Web Services Response with ksoap2?

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2, mtom

I search around, but don't really find the solution.
So I have successfully connected to the web services.

But I got error in HttpTransportSE.call function.

```
07-22 16:11:14.927    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT
07-22 16:11:14.938    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ --uuid:924b7fe0...@5:13 in java.io.InputStreamReader@3e8848c4)
07-22 16:11:14.956    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:432)
07-22 16:11:14.964    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
07-22 16:11:14.990    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:2048)
07-22 16:11:15.010    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:127)
07-22 16:11:15.029    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:129)
07-22 16:11:15.048    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.parseResponse(HttpTransportSE.java:301)
07-22 16:11:15.066    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:274)
07-22 16:11:15.083    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
07-22 16:11:15.100    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
07-22 16:11:15.119    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace.MapsActivity.getXml(MapsActivity.java:115)
07-22 16:11:15.139    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace.MapsActivity.setUpMap(MapsActivity.java:98)
07-22 16:11:15.159    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace.MapsActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(MapsActivity.java:77)
07-22 16:11:15.178    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:45)
07-22 16:11:15.196    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
07-22 16:11:15.216    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
07-22 16:11:15.236    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
07-22 16:11:15.256    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
07-22 16:11:15.275    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
07-22 16:11:15.294    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
07-22 16:11:15.310    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-22 16:11:15.326    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-22 16:11:15.343    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
07-22 16:11:15.358    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-22 16:11:15.376    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-22 16:11:15.395    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-22 16:11:15.411    2341-2341/com.ecocean.ecoceansharkrace W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I got all my data in response dump on xml MTOM format.

```
--uuid:83c4c128-fbc9-4d82-bc23-4aec6f9a87d3
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="application/soap+xml";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap:Body><csvResponse xmlns="http://service.dataxmldistribution.argos.cls.fr/types"><return>
"3492";"149343";"WHAL_SH";"SPOT5";"";"NP";"2015-07-17T06:41:18.000Z";"873";"16";"0";"-120";"4.0167724272E8";"2015-07-17T06:39:30.000Z";"-21.93907";"114.13805";"0.0";"1";"";"";
"3492";"149343";"WHAL_SH";"SPOT5";"";"NP";"2015-07-17T08:26:20.000Z";"598";"13";"0";"-126";"4.0167724402E8";"2015-07-17T08:17:07.000Z";"-21.93158";"114.13424";"0.0";"3";"";"";
"3492";"149343";"WHAL_SH";"SPOT5";"";"SR";"2015-07-17T09:10:48.000Z";"690";"16";"0";"-124";"4.0167724414E8";"2015-07-17T09:09:38.000Z";"-21.93184";"114.13853";"0.0";"3";"";"";
"3492";"149343";"WHAL_SH";"SPOT5";"";"NN";"2015-07-17T09:16:56.000Z";"873";"12";"0";"-121";"4.0167724541E8";"2015-07-17T09:05:48.000Z";"-21.94773";"114.12561";"0.0";"3";"";"";
"3492";"149343";"WHAL_SH";"SPOT5";"";"NK";"2015-07-17T09:41:28.000Z";"690";"14";"1";"-117";"4.0167725269E8";"2015-07-17T09:32:15.000Z";"-21.93693";"114.12813";"0.0";"3";"";"";
"3492";"149343";"WHAL_SH";"SPOT5";"";"MA";"2015-07-18T00:44:03.000Z";"736";"15";"5";"-116";"4.0167723194E8";"2015-07-18T00:39:48.000Z";"-21.93588";"114.11965";"0.0";"3";"";"";
"3492";"149343";"WHAL_SH";"SPOT5";"";"MB";"2015-07-18T01:36:11.000Z";"828";"16";"1";"-118";"4.0167722211E8";"2015-07-18T01:34:39.000Z";"-21.93369";"114.13258";"0.0";"1";"";"";
"3492";"149343";"WHAL_SH";"SPOT5";"";"MA";"2015-07-18T02:23:43.000Z";"782";"18";"9";"-110";"4.0167721526E8";"2015-07-18T02:14:08.000Z";"-21.93924";"114.14502";"0.0";"1";"";"";
"3492";"149343";"WHAL_SH";"SPOT5";"";"MB";"2015-07-18T03:10:29.000Z";"0";"1";"0";"-133";"4.0167720194E8";"2015-07-18T03:10:29.000Z";"-21.93436";"114.13397";"0.0";"B";"";"";</return></csvResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--uuid:83c4c128-fbc9-4d82-bc23-4aec6f9a87d3--
```

So I think the error comes out because the xml response is in MTOM format and ksoap2 lib doesn't understand it.

Anyone have solution for this problem ?

How to edit the response so I can get the

```
<Envelope>..</Envelope>
```

part and send it for parsing ?

Thank you.

Here is my code

```
public String getXml (String username, String password, String PlatformId, String nbDaysFromNow) {
        String data = null;
        String methodname = "csvRequest";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodname);
        request.addProperty("username", username);
        request.addProperty("password", password);
        request.addProperty("platformId", PlatformId);
        request.addProperty("nbDaysFromNow", nbDaysFromNow);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = getSoapSerializationEnvelope(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = getHttpTransportSE();
        try {
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive resultsString = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

            data = resultsString.toString();

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception q) {
            q.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;

    }

    private final SoapSerializationEnvelope getSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapObject request) {
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        return envelope;
    }

    private final HttpTransportSE getHttpTransportSE() {
        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(Proxy.NO_PROXY,MAIN_REQUEST_URL,60000);
        ht.debug = true;
        ht.setXmlVersionTag("<!--?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?-->");
        return ht;
    }
```